# Graphic glitches ubuntu 19.10

Tags: google-chrome, amd-graphics, 19.10, amd-ryzen

I am running Ubuntu 19.10 on Huawei matebook d14 with AMD Ryzen 5 2500U and AMD Radeon Vega 8. I very often keep getting weird graphic glitches on chrome and sometimes in other apps and system settings. Here is gallery with screentshots i managed to take https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWzfO.jpg
Glitches disappear when i scroll page/minimize and maximize the window.
Let me know if you need any more info or logs. I am a newbie ubuntu user